# Python updating dictionary but need to get the key pair?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, key

Given this dictionary format:

name: (id, type1, type2, hp, attack, defense, speed, generation, legendary)
dict={'Bulbasaur': (1, 'Grass', 'Poison', 45, 49, 49, 45, 1, False)}

I need to go through the database (dictionary of multiple pokemon with their stats in the provided format) and find which pokemon have legendary status, which is a boolean value. I need to count the types that are legendary and put them in a new dictionary.

So for example if Bulbasaur was legendary, Grass type=1 Poison type=1. New dictionary item would be :

new_dict={"Grass": 1, "Poison": 1}

I made the code to get the types extracted and then count which types are legendary but I am stuck on how to get the final dictionary with type and count number.

Here is the code that I have:

```
def legendary_count_of_types(db):

    Fire=0
    Grass=0
    Flying=0
    Poison=0
    Dragon=0
    Water=0
    Fighting=0
    Ground=0
    Ghost=0
    Rock=0
    Ice=0
    d={}
    for key,values in db.items():
        status=values[8]
        if status==True:
            type_list=get_types(db)
            for item in type_list:
                if item=='Fire':
                    Fire+=1
                if item=='Grass':
                    Grass+=1
                if item=='Flying':
                    Flying+=1
                if item=='Poison':
                    Poison+=1
                if item=='Dragon':
                    Dragon+=1
                if item=='Water':
                    Water+=1
                if item=='Fighting':
                    Fighting+=1
                if item=='Ground':
                    Ground+=1
                if item=='Ghost':
                    Ghost+=1
                if item=='Rock':
                    Rock+=1
                if item=='Ice':
                    Ice+=1
    d.update()
    #how do I get the key value pair?
    return d
```

Here is what my get_types function does:

```
def get_types(db):
    l=[]
    s=[]
    for key,values in db.items():
        types1=str(values[1])
        types2-str(values[2])
        l.apppend(types1)
        l.append(types2)
    for i in l:
        if i not in s:
            s.append(i)
            if 'None' in s:
                s.remove('None')
    final_list=s
    return sorted(final_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you just want a count of the times a type appears in a legendary Pokemon, without using anything fancy like pandas (which you probably ought to be doing with your data collection, or maybe a little sql db)

```
type_counter = dict() # or use collections.Counter
for name, attributes in db.items()
    is_legendary = attributes[8]
    if is_legendary:
        type1 = attributes[1]
        type2 = attributes[2]  
        type_counter[type1] = type_counter.get(type1, 0) + 1
        type_counter[type2] = type_counter.get(type2, 0) + 1

# type_counter will now be a dictionary with the counts.
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am not allowed to import any modules. @nimish

Comment: Edited, Counter is just a dictionary with some enhancements.

Comment: It's running into errors when there are none listed as types. {'Dragon': 1, 'Fire': 4, None: 2, 'Flying':[37 chars]': 1} != {'Grass': 1, 'Fire': 4, 'Flying': 2, 'Poiso[41 chars]': 1} How can I filter out the 'None' type?

Comment: Well, you have both types in the body of the loop-- you should be able to filter out cases where there's only one type. Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: I have a different assignment that is similar but I wanted to see if I could do it with pokemon stats.

Comment: OK, so you should be able to use an if-statement to check for the case in which the second type is None.